# Table Not Generating in PHPMyAdmin for PHP-Login

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Below is the SQL Code Which I am trying to Execute in PHPMyAdmin for creating tables of PHP-Login project but the code doesn't create any tables, I am unable to figure out the problem here..

It just shows:

> "Your SQL query has been executed successfully (Query took 0.0010 sec)"

but it doesn't generate any tables..

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `login`.`users` (
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'auto incrementing user_id of each user, unique index',
 `user_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'user''s name, unique',
 `user_password_hash` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'user''s password in salted and hashed format',
 `user_email` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'user''s email, unique',
 `user_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'user''s activation status',
 `user_account_type` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'user''s account type (basic, premium, etc)',
 `user_has_avatar` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '1 if user has a local avatar, 0 if not',
 `user_rememberme_token` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'user''s remember-me cookie token',
 `user_creation_timestamp` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'timestamp of the creation of user''s account',
 `user_last_login_timestamp` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'timestamp of user''s last login',
 `user_failed_logins` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'user''s failed login attempts',
 `user_last_failed_login` int(10) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'unix timestamp of last failed login attempt',
 `user_activation_hash` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'user''s email verification hash string',
 `user_password_reset_hash` char(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'user''s password reset code',
 `user_password_reset_timestamp` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'timestamp of the password reset request',
 `user_provider_type` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
 `user_facebook_uid` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'optional - facebook UID',
 PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `user_name` (`user_name`),
 UNIQUE KEY `user_email` (`user_email`),
 KEY `user_facebook_uid` (`user_facebook_uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='user data';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Do you have permissions to create a new table? (Maybe you're logged in with a user you created without this permission.

2) Before executing the query, did you execute the correct USE $DBNAME? If not, your table will be created somewhere random, or most probably won't be created at all.

Comment: My Mistake was not executing the correct DB Name .. Instead of Login I had to use testing as it was the DB that I created.. Thanks for helping.
I forgot to replace the name of the DB in

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `login`.`users` (

to CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testing`.`users` (

coz I was creating DB with the name of "testing" .. Btw thanks for the suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Result after run your in my phpmyadmin]

May be problem in you db or permission issue or mysql version because your query works fine as you can see in screen shots

Comment: Thanks for the Screenshot and I have figured out what went wrong to my table creation process.. I forgot to replace the name of the DB in

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `login`.`users` (

to CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testing`.`users` (

coz I was creating DB with the name of "testing" .. Btw thanks for the suggestion...